# Aggregate events / goals per user

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know if there's a way to display information based on how many (similar) goals or events were triggered by a unique user.

For instance, let's say I own amazon. For every product I sell, I trigger a 'Purchase' goal (by using an event).

I would like to know:

1. How many products does an average user buy, in multiple sessions, over a time span. for instance, how many products did an average user buy in the span of a month.
2. I would like to segment data by the amount of products bought by users. i.e. segmenting my data based on users that bought 0 products, 1-5 products, 6-10, products, and 11+ products.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get custom dimension/metric in GA. Add a custom dimension '*product_quantity*' and get actual number of products bought as metric value in the variable.

Once you get have it, you do calculation of total products divided by users or creating segments based on *product_quantity* dimension.

Find more info at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

It is easier with Google Tag Manager. Once you define custom dimension/metric, trigger may be completion of 'Purchase' goal or any event.